# Python List Comprehension for Database Data

Tags: python, list, for-loop, list-comprehension

I am trying to reduce duplicates in a SQL Server database table and the criteria are complicated. All table data has been pulled into Python `list`s.

In this step, I want to use a list comprehension to find a certain field value when one `list` value matches the `list` value of the `list` that has duplicates in rows.

`list` A is a unique list of `dupID`s: `[134L, 1610L, 1861L, 2026L, 3211L, 4134L, 4363L, 4453L, 4733L,...]`

`list` B is two-dimensional:

```
  Row#    dupID    nameID   SSN           personID

[[85097L, 236479L, 241583, '999-99-0000', 359913, datetime.datetime(2012, 9, 9, 0, 0)]

 [78654L, 236479L, 996783, '999-99-0000', NULL,   datetime.datetime(2008, 5, 4, 0, 0)]...]
```

These are the loops that I want to speed up through a list comprehension:

```
personIDList = []
for i in range(len(A)):
        for j in range(len(B)):
             if A[i] == B[j][1]: # if dupID == dupID
                   personIDList.append(B[j][4]) # append personID
```

Comment: "I want to speed up through a list comprehension"? What makes you think a list comprehension would be faster?

Answer (score 3):

Convert the unique ID list to a set first:

```
s = set(A)
```

Then iterate over the other list using a list comprehension:

```
personIDList = [item[4] for item in B if item[1] in s]
```

This is going to be `O(N)` in complexity compared to your approach which is `O(N**2)`.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you would iterate over the elements not the indexes, so you would get this:

```
personIDList = []
for a in A:
    for b in B:
        if a == b[1]:
            personIDList.append(b[4])
```

This can be then easily turned into a list comprehension:

```
personIDList = [b[4] for a in A for b in B if a == b[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you turn a single for loop into a list comprehension:

```
my_list = []
for i in something:
    my_list.append(i+7)
```

goes to

```
my_list = [i+7 for i in something]
```

Here is how you turn nested for loops into a list comprehension:

```
my_list = []
for i in first_thing:
    for j in second_thing:
        my_list.append(i + j)
```

goes to

```
my_list = [i + j for i in first_thing for j in second_thing]
```

So in your case you want to do this:

```
personIDList = [b[4] for a in A for b in B if a == b[1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array(A)
B = np.array(B)
person_ids = B[np.in1d(list(B[:,1]),A)][:,4]
```

I think at least ... it would be easier if you posted example A and B lists

I always like doing numpy stuff :P

we can make this more readable by breaking it apart

```
dup_ids_in_b = list(B[:,1]) # take column 1 from B (we use list so its not of type `object`)
boolmask_b_dups_in_a = np.in1d(dup_ids_in_b,A) # True,True,False,... True for all indices where B[i][1] is in A
person_ids = B[boolmask_b_dups_in_a][:,4] # take the fourth column of all the True indices from last step
```

Comment: Thanks very much for everyone's help! I will post what I do.